# Custom Jade Renderer

Tags: node.js, templates, pug, frontend

I would like to change the code before or after jade render HTML. I need to change the code to add some specific functions. For example

```
h4#headline Click to register
a(href="myLink", data-type="foo") Here
```

I would like to prepare all links or html tags with data-type by the value in the tag. 
Is that possible or has anybody experience with that?

Thanks for help!

Comment: possibly use http://jade-lang.com/reference/#mixins? Are you looking to add to all html tags?

Comment: your question is not clear to me. **by the value in the tag** what you mean? Please show an example of an input and your desired output.